# Erroneous caching of fields in a productpage by Chrome

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, google-chrome, caching

I have a kind of paged catalogwebsite with the pages filled with Jsondata by AngularJs. Server side is ASP.Net MVC. Since a couple of months Chrome is caching some fields in a page with a single visitor. The cached fields are the short number fiels in the page. The description and URL to a thumbnail are correct. I was not able to reproduce the matter jet. Only once I had access to a computer with the problem and fiddling with the settings in the advanced/languages (spellceck and languages) resolved the problem definitive. However, I was not able to get the erroneous behavior back in any way.

What I tried:

- Get the Json data with a POST.
- Decorate the Controller methods with:
  [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]

Suggestions what I can try next?

regards

Comment: This is one of those problems that has too many variables that could be affecting the issue. It could be an issue with your AngularJS app and local storage, it could be an issue with a caching layer like Redis (if you even have that) and it could be an issue with caching certain responses in the browser because you aren't sending the right headers from the server. On top of that, you can't reliably reproduce the issue. I am not sure we can give you a great answer here.

Comment: Sure, there are many variables. I'am not that experienced and ask for suggestion where to look. I am out of options. I don't use Redis.  All the data (fields) is in one response and the numeric type fields are cached.